# Huge size of SharePoint content DB! Why?

Tags: sharepoint-2007

We have very strange problem. Our webapp quota is 700 MB and now used only 520 MB, but content db of this webapp now is 19 GB!!!
What is in 18 GB stored if my content only 520 MB???!!! Anybody can me explain?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem with two of my SharePoint content databases. In my case, it happened to be that the AuditData table is huge. Look at your Site Collection Audit Settings.

Comment: You are right! AuditData table size 18GB now!!!

Answer (score 0):

Just shooting from the hip. Is there anything in the Recycle Bin on Sharepoint?

Comment: No Recycle Bin is empty!

Answer (score 0):

Have you made changes to the default pages?  My guess is you went from [ghosted to unghosted pages](http://www.etechplanet.com/post/2009/03/30/Ghosted-and-Unghosted-Pages-in-SharePoint.aspx)

Comment: Yes, we change masterpage and other default pages - such as dispform.aspx...

Comment: We have many unghosted pages, but 18GB!!! 18GB of unghosted pages is very strange...

Answer (score 0):

You can always try and shrink the log files in controlled way. I have detailed the steps in my blog for doing this:
http://shareyourpoint.wordpress.com/2013/03/22/how-to-manage-large-sharepoint-configuration-database-logfile/

Comment: Welcome to Server Fault! While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.